# Call C# function from html button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

### Explanation

I am working on an e-commerce website and I'm currently working on the cart section. Now all the products that are added to the cart are stored in a static list. For all the products in the list there will be html code generated.

```
protected void btnCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show howmany items are in the cart list
        lblCartCount.Text = "There are currently " + (CartList.Count()).ToString() + " items in your cart";

        //Clear current cart-html code
        CartProducts.InnerHtml = String.Empty;

        //Foreach product in the cart list
        for (int i = 0; i < CartList.Count; i++)
        {
            //Get necessary info about the current looped product
            var TupleProductInfo = B.GetProductInfo(CartList[i]);
            int ProductID = TupleProductInfo.Item1;
            String ProductSize = TupleProductInfo.Item2;
            double ProductPrice = TupleProductInfo.Item3;

                //Foreach product cleate cart-html
                CartProducts.InnerHtml += 
                    "<div class='CartProduct'>" +
                        "<div>" +
                            "<h4>" + B.GetProductName(ProductID) + "</h4>" +
                        "<button id='btnDeleteProduct' runat='server' onserverclick='btnDeleteProduct_click' title='remove product'>" +
                            "<i class='fas fa-times fa-lg'></i>" +
                        "</button >" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div>" +
                            "<p>Size: " + ProductSize + "</p>" +
                            "<p>Price: €" + Math.Round(ProductPrice, 2) + "</p>" +
                            "<p>Amount: " + CartListAmount[i].ToString() + "</p>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>";
            }

        //Show the cart 
        popupCart.Style.Add("display", "flex");
        }
```

```
        <div runat="server" id="CartProducts" class="margin2"></div>
```

Each with a button to delete the product from the cart.

```
<button id='btnDeleteProduct' runat='server' onserverclick='btnDeleteProduct_click' title='remove product'>
```

When I click the button to delete the product from the cart I want to call a C# function.

```
protected void btnDeleteProduct_click(object sender, EventArgs e){ ... }
```

### What is the problem

The function is not getting called.

### What I tried

- use the html-element input instead of button
- call a jquery function that call's a C# function
- use a form

### Conclusion

I appreciate that you took a look at my problem!
If you know any solution or you have an alternative please let me know.
Pleases excuse me if I didn't use Stack Overflow 100% correct, any tips are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all you cannot create a button as a string with `runat=server` and/or `OnServerClick` in it. That won't work. You will need Dynamic Controls. Second making the cart `static` means that all users will see and use the same cart contents!

Comment: Hi, Thanks alot for the advice! What do you recommend as an alternative to display the cart products with the possibility to delete them from the cart?

Comment: As @VDWWD said, use *dynamic controls*, like this `Button btnDeleteProduct = new Button(); btnDeleteProduct.Text = "remove product"; btnDeleteProduct.ID = "btnDeleteProduct_" + i;  btnDeleteProduct.Click += new EventHandler(btnDeleteProduct_click); CartProducts.Controls.Add(btnDeleteProduct);`. Notice that `ID` is unique for every button.

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to generate HTML on the fly - then Web Forms is not the framework for you. You'd be much better off with ASP.NET Core MVC, or Blazor, or perhaps a JavaScript framework such as Vue, React, or Angular. Web Forms is a real pain. Also you mentioned a static list for the shopping cart - I hope that's just for demo purposes and you know that static objects are shared by everyone hitting your site, so they'll all share the same shopping cart in this case.

Comment: If you really want to use webforms and create a cart, you could do something like this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9f0ae2/gridview-edit-delete-and-update-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for some time, I still coudn't get the function to be called (I tried the above suggestions). So I solved it as following: I made a Session with all the products of my cart and redirected to a separate page. On this page I made a datalist and wrote a SelectCommand to select all the items in the session

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!!

Replace and Work !

```
"<button id='btnDeleteProduct' runat='server' OnClick=\"btnDeleteProduct()\"  title='remove product'>" +


public void btnDeleteProduct()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
```